# Class: ECHO is off from batbox

Tags: batch-file

I wanted to make a little game using batbox. I wanted it to display which class you used but it didn't work. It showed "Class: ECHO is off." And I don't know what's wrong. Here's the code I used:

```
:charectarselect
cd gamedata
color 0f
cls
batbox /g 0 0
echo Select class:
echo.
echo %mage%
echo %worrior%
set /p classes=Class: 

echo %classes%>pclass.gm
goto login

:login
color 0f
cd gamedata
set /p pclass=<pclass.gm
set /p user=<username.gm
set /p pass=<password.gm
if "%pclass%" == "1" echo Mage>pclass.gm
cls
title Login
echo ======================LOGIN======================
set /p login=Username : 

if %login% == %user% goto password
goto login
:password
cls
echo ======================LOGIN======================
set /p passw=Password : 

if %passw% == %pass% goto game
goto password

:game
cls
batbox /c 0xc9 /d "Health: %health%"
batbox /g 11 0 /c 0x9c /d "Strength: %strength%"
batbox /g 23 0 /c 0x9a /d "Class: %pclass%"
pause >nul
```

Comment: Did you mean that it's displaying "ECHO is off" before it asks for class? That's the only place I see that message; it's coming from the `%mage%` and `%worrior%` [sic] variables not being defined. Once I enter the class name, the variable display in the `:name` section displays correctly.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/54fb45340015b418fb33822a5e31e9fe This is what i get @SomethingDark

Comment: _Wait a second..._ You're entering `1` for class, aren't you?

Comment: Yeah? @SomethingDark

Comment: @SomethingDark But in the start of the login screen i tell it to be Mage

Comment: I know exactly what's wrong. Let me put this in an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by you entering `1` for class. Specifically, it's caused by the line `echo %classes%>pclass.gm`

When you entered 1 in character selection, it expands that command to `echo 1>pclass.gm`. Unfortunately, `1>` is used to redirect output from STDOUT to a file, and so batch is interpreting this as a command to send the output of `echo` to pclass.gm. By itself, `echo` displays whether echo is on or off.

You can get around this by adding parentheses to the echo line:
`(echo %classes%)>pclass.gm`

Comment: Thanks for the help :3 @SomethingDark

Comment: Can i ask you some thing else? ;-; @SomethingDark Ok so it worked and now i want a monster to damage but when i type "set health -= %monsterdmg%" can you help again? and sorry.

Comment: @minefedtgamer - Use `set /a health-=%monsterdmg%` instead. The `/a` option is what allows `set` to use math.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I am having so many problems and i dont know why. Please answer my newest post?? and again i am so sorry